# R Shiny Dashboard: not able to create a Box

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to include a fileinput in Shiny Dashboard sidebar, and a box in dashboard body and despite of my several attempts, I am not able to see any box in my dashboard body as long as my fileinput is in Sidebar. Every help is important. Thanks Again.

Following is 1 Sample Code

```
#UI   
library(shinydashboard)

dashboardPage(
 dashboardHeader(title= "my dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(width=250,
   sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Data UpLoad", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("table"),
        fileInput('file1','Choose CSV File',
                  accept=c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv'))),
    menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
  )),
dashboardBody(
 tabItems(
 #first tab content
 tabItem(tabName="dashboard",
  fluidRow(
   box(title="Data",solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = 
    TRUE,tableOutput("table1"))
      )
      ),
 tabItem(tabName="widgets")))
  )

#server

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)


server <- function(input, output) {
output$table1= renderTable({
  inFile=input$file1

 if(is.null(inFile))
return(NULL)
read.csv(inFile$datapath)
 })
 }
```

Comment: Its not the issue with the`box`, instead `menuItem` that has child elements cant be used  to control `tabItem`. Refer to this [link](https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/28). You will find a workaround to the issue you are facing in the same link. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Bista- Thanks for the reference, I was facing an another issue which I solved after writing the whole in different app and it worked :-)